# is mapnik node module available for higher version of node(like 4.0.0)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mapnik

Currently I am using node version 0.12.0. I wanted to switch to node version 4.0.0 but I doubt if mapnik works on higher version. Because in documentation they have specified it only for Node v0.10.x or v0.12.x.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with NodeJS v4.2.6 and node-mapnik v3.4.16, these are the most current releases at this point. There are also a few discussions about NodeJS 4.x compatibility on the node-mapnik Github repository, it seems that the readme is just outdated.

I ran the following script to verify:

```
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var fs = require('fs');

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();
var map = new mapnik.Map(800, 600);
map.loadSync("map.xml");
map.zoomAll();
map.renderFileSync("out.png");
console.log(map);
```